# react native 0.72-rc6 android relase error

Tags: android, react-native

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease' (type 'AndroidLintAnalysisTask').

Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Users/tom/Documents/GitHub/media/android/app/build/intermediates/ReactNativeVectorIcons'.

Reason: Task ':app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease' uses this output of task ':app:copyReactNativeVectorIconFonts' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.

Possible solutions:

Declare task ':app:copyReactNativeVectorIconFonts' as an input of ':app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease'.
Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:copyReactNativeVectorIconFonts' from ':app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease' using Task#dependsOn.
Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:copyReactNativeVectorIconFonts' from ':app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease' using Task#mustRunAfter.
Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
```

Comment: I have similar issue with react-native-signature-capture:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':react-native-signature-capture:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars' (type 'LibraryJniLibsTask').
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'xxxxx/node_modules/react-native-signature-capture/android/build/intermediates/stripped_native_libs/release/out'.    
etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is mostly due to react-native-vector-icons . it is working fine in debug mode but while creating release apk or bundle this issue is raising . the solution was to ceate a patch of react-native-vector-icons.

in the below file i have added the following line.

```
node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle b/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle



android.applicationVariants.all { def variant ->
        def targetName = variant.name.capitalize() // add this
        def lintVitalAnalyzeTask = tasks.findByName("lintVitalAnalyze${targetName}") // add this
        if (lintVitalAnalyzeTask) { // add this
            lintVitalAnalyzeTask.dependsOn(fontCopyTask) // add this
        } // add this
         def generateAssetsTask = tasks.findByName("generate${targetName}Assets")
         generateAssetsTask.dependsOn(fontCopyTask)
     }
```